# Content offset stays constant

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I've got a `UIPageViewController` in my app, set up like this:

```
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainPageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I've made my `UIViewController` conform to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and added this code to set the scrollView delegate to `self`:

```
    for (UIView *currentView in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
    if ([currentView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)currentView;
        scrollView.delegate = self;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to use this method to find the current page, though the `contentOffset` stays the same whenever I scroll the `UIPageViewController`:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
NSInteger page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;

NSLog(@"Content offset.x: %.f", scrollView.contentOffset.x);
}
```

**Why is this?**

Answer (score 3):

I made it work using a delegate method of the `UIPageViewController` rather than the scrollView. This is my solution:

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    if (completed) {
        NSInteger currentIndex = [self.navViewControllers indexOfObject:pageViewController.viewControllers[0]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting confusing values from the contentOffset.x of the PageViewController's scrollView, and this solution is a great (and even cleaner) work-around.